# Getting Users OS Version Using PHP

Tags: php, macos, user-agent

I am needing to identify the browser and OS version of users to a website. Particularly the Mac OS Catalina. If anyone visiting the site using Safari and Catalina need to be redirected to a different page than all other visitors.

Can anyone assist me with PHP for such a need?

Answer (score 1):

You could get infomation of user browser with $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']. Let view https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: It would be more convenient for the user If you can write few lines helping the person understand and share the reference link as well.

Comment: Thanks but I am unsure how to use it to gather the browser and operating system version so that I can then redirect the user if they are on Mac Catalina and Safari.